# Powershell Enviroment Variables not found

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I'm trying to create a Shortcut for a powershell script that uses [Environment]::UserName the shortcut will be started from the correct user I want to read from env variable.

%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noexit -File "C:\test\test.ps1"

This the target on the shortcut. How can I make Env variables work?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't say what wasn't working.  Where in the script are you using the [Environment]::UserName and what happens?

Comment: $user = [Environment]::UserName and I'm trying to use $user as a variable in a path. It returns blank

Comment: @rgomez I can't recreate the behavior your describing. an environment variable is still present even if I call a script from a shortcut. Is ```[Environment]::UserName ``` used in your test.ps1 file? if so please show the file. I need more detail to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The powershell syntax i use for environment variables is

```
$env:username
```

If you are using it in a string or path you need to make sure the parsing order is correct.

```
$($env:username)
```

so if your username is user1 and you want path

```
C:\Users\user1\test.ps1
```

you would use

```
C:\Users\$($env:username)\test.ps1
```

Comment: That's how I'm using it but when loading powershell from a shortcut I'm getting that enviroment variable empty. I guess because powershell load is made different way than when you go to prompt opening a regular powershell console.